# Can one implement a Dart command line WebSocket client that supports two-way exchanges with a server?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to create command line Dart apps that have two goals:

- They can be easily launched in debugging mode from IntelliJ (IJ) or the Dart Editor (DE) without involving the Dartium browser as I develop Java-based web services that will run in an embedded Jetty server. This will support a TDD workflow.
- By incorporating Dart unit tests, each app could become a web service tester that can be run under Jenkins.

It appears that importing dart:html in a source file triggers expectations in both IJ and DE that an HTML page is the entry point into the Dart main(). Also (in IJ), the Select/Run/Debug items in the context menu are not added for Dart source files that import dart:html but are for my unittest source files without this import statement. This complicates the workflow by requiring that my Dartium browser become involved. I have successfully created a simple echo WS script using the recipe shown in the section [A Command Line WebSocket Client](http://jamesslocum.com/post/74731227156), but this example only listens for but does not send messages. In fact, the API of the io:WebSocket has no 'send' method as does its html:WebSocket counterpart. The io:WebSocket appears to be much weaker than its 'html' counterpart. So for my use cases (or for someone trying to write a middle-tier Dart-based server), can this be done and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. As far as I remember in `dart:io` it is just `add` instead of `send`. I didn't have the impression that the `io:WebSocket` has less capabilities.

See https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.WebSocket#id_add
You have to click the `add` link below `Methods` (deep links don't work properly yet in api.dartlang.org).

Comment: @gz It worked. Thanks. My initial impression was formed from not seeing the send* methods, but I haven't used the io:WebSocket before so I stand corrected. Could these two classes benefit from having their APIs aligned?

Comment: There are several such discrepancies between `dart:html` and `dart:io`. `dart:html` reuses the names from the browser API, `dart:io` uses the names the Dart team thought appropriate. There is the `http` package which does some unification between client and server and there were discussions for such a package for file access as well. The problem is that a unified API can at most provide what the least capable implementation supports and the limiting factor is currently the APIs in the browser. I'm not sure if it adds much value to have an unified API for a limited set of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I do pretty extensive work with server-side WebSocket programming in Dart, and it seems quite full-featured to me. Lately, I've been using the [Redstone framework](http://redstonedart.org/) with the [WebSocket plugin](http://redstonedart.org/doc/redstone_web_socket.html), which removes much of the boilerplate and makes it almost too easy...

Comment: Very helpful and answers one of the deeper questions I had.